# Getting the error Response code: No response Response message: Read timeout, no response received

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using Jmeter for the load testing of an application which includes web socket connection.

When trying to read the data in a frame using Single Read Sampler,got an error Response code: No response Response message: Read timeout, no response received.

Can anybody help me in solving this issue?

Thread Name: Missouri TestEnv 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-10-09 10:40:43 IST
Load time: 1000
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: No response
Response message: Read timeout, no response received.

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/)

> **WebSocket Single Read Sampler** - Receives text or binary WebSocket frames

So I can think of 2 reasons:

1. Your Single Read Sampler configuration is not correct, i.e. wrong protocol/host/port/path/etc. Cross check the settings with i.e. [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools). For example you're using `wss` protocol with port `80` however the port should be `443` or something like that
2. Your application doesn't automatically send frames over the established connection, to wit it requires some input from your side. If this is the case make sure to send something to the endpoint using i.e. WebSocket Single Write Sampler

You might find [Single read sample.jmx](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers/blob/master/samples/Single%20read%20sample.jmx) example test plan useful.

---

If you will be experiencing problems consider adding the following lines to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

then restart JMeter and re-run your test and look into [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file - it should contain verbose debugging information on what's going on under the hood, most probably you will be able to figure out the cause of the problem from there.

Comment: I have added the Webscoket request response sampler in the script and am getting Response code: 200
Response message: Number of samples in transaction : 5, number of failing samples : 0 this is fine

But in the server logs the response messages are not saved , we are not getting proper count in message logs could you please help me out